# How to use values of the Hashmap regardless keys in MongoDB query format

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, microservices

I have a hashmap

```
public HashMap<String, String> variableValues;
```

I want to use the values of this hashmap in MongoDB query format like,

```
@Query(value = "{ 'clientId' : ?0, $or : [ 
       { 'account.name' : { $regex : ?1 , $options : 'i' } } ,
       { 'account.contactNo' : { $regex : ?1 , $options : 'i' } } ,
       { 'account.emailId' : { $regex : ?1 , $options : 'i' } } ,
       { 'contacts.contactNo' : { $regex : ?1 , $options : 'i' } } ,
       { 'contacts.email' : { $regex : ?1 , $options : 'i' } } ,
       { 'contacts.name' : { $regex : ?1 , $options : 'i' } } ,
       { 'variableValues.$' : { $regex : ?1 , $options : 'i' } } ] }",
    sort = "{ 'lastEngaged' : -1.0 }")
    List<CustomerAccounts> advancedSearchInCustomerAccounts(Long clientId, String pattern, Pageable pageable);
```

how to do this?

Comment: Please review the tags: does *Spring*, *Spring Boot*, and/or *microservices* help define the topic of this question?